# How can I rewrite this Python operation so it doesn't hang my system?

Tags: python

Beginner here, looked for an answer, but can't find one.

I know (or rather suspect) that part of the problem with the following code is how big the list of combinations gets.

(Maybe too, the last line seems like an error, in that, if I just run 'print ...' rather than 'comb += ...' it runs quickly and quits.  Would 'append' be more graceful?)

I'm not 100% sure if the system hang is due to disk I/O (swapping?), CPU use, or memory... running it under Windows seems to result in a rather large disk I/O by 'System', while under Linux, top was showing high CPU and memory use before it was killed.  In both cases though, the rest of the system was unusable while this operation was going (tried it in the Python interpreter directly, as well as in PyCharm).

So two part question:  1) is there some 'safe' way to test code like this that won't affect the rest of the system negatively, and 2) for this specific example, how should I rewrite it?

Trying this code (which I do not recommend!):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
comb = []
iterable = [1,2,3,4]
for x in xrange(4,100):
  comb += cwr(iterable, x)
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Should have specified, but it is python2.7 code here as well (guess the xrange makes it obvious it's not 3 anyways).  The Windows machine that's hanging has 4 GB of RAM, but it looks like the hang is on disk I/O.  The original problem I was (and still am) working on was a question at codewars.com, about how many ways to make change given a list of possible coins and an amount to make.  The solution I'd come up with worked for small amounts, and not big ones.  Obviously, I need to come up with a better algorithm to solve that problem... so this is non-essential code,  certainly.  However, I would like to know if there's something I can do to set the programming environment so that bugs in my code don't propagate and choke my system this way.

FURTHER EDIT:
I was working on the problem again tonight, and realized that I didn't need to append to a master list (as some of you hinted to me in the comments), but just work on the subset that was collected.  I hadn't really given enough of the code to make that obvious, but my key problem here was the line:

comb += cwr(iterable, x)

which should have been

comb = cwr(iterable, x)

Comment: Not that this helps you but on my macbook air, python2.7, anaconda, this code works fine. It says is a ~2.6GB of ram. Maybe that is your issue.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because that's way too many tuples

Comment: You could inject a tiny sleep between iterations that will let you hit ctrl-c, perhaps. Given the size of the problem, it won't really delay the task much

Comment: Why do you need a `list` of this, anyway?

Comment: Edited the main post: the Windows machine has 4GB RAM, hang appears to be on Disk I/O, it's non-essential code that I'm rewriting anyway, my main question is really if there's something I can do to make it so my system doesn't grind to a halt when I run some buggy code like this.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are trying to compute combinations with replacement, the number of orderings that must be considered will be **4^nth power**.(4 because your iterable has 4 items).

More generally speaking, the number of orderings to be computed is the number of elements that can be at any spot in the list, raised to the power of how long the list is.

You are trying to compute 4^nth power for n between 3 and 99. 4^99 power is **4.01734511064748 * 10<sup>59</sup>**.

I'm afraid not even a quantum computer would be much help computing that.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very powerful laptop (3.7 GiB,Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2820 @ 2.13GHz × 2, 64bit ubuntu) but it did it in 15s or so (but did slow noticeably, top showed 100% cpu (dual core) and 35% memory. It took about 15s to release the memory when if finished.

len(comb) was 4,421,240

I had to change your code to

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
comb = []
iterable = [1,2,3,4]
for x in xrange(4,100):
  comb.extend(list(cwr(iterable, x)))
```

ED - just re-tried as per your original and it does run OK. My mistake. It looks as though it is the memory requirement. If you really need to do this you could write it to a file.

re-ED being curious about the back-of-an-envelope complexity calculation above not squaring my experience, I tried plotting n (X axis) against the length of list returned by combinations_with_replacement() (Y axis) for iterable lengths 2,3,4,5 i. The result seems to be below n**(i-1) (Which ties in with the figure I got for 4,99 above. It's actually (i+n-1)! / n! / (i-1)! which approximates to n**(i-1)/i! for n much bigger than i)

[image: log log plot of list size v. n for different lengths of iterable]

Also, running the plot I didn't keep the full comb list in memory and this did improve computer performance quite a bit, so maybe that's a relevant point: rather than produce a giant list then work on it afterwords, do the calculations in the loop.